# php regex to remove CSS vendor prefix hell

Tags: php, prefixfree

I am trying to cleanup my CSS documents to remove only those vendor-prefixed lines:

```
-webkit-......;
-o-.....;
-ms-......;
-khtml-......;
-moz-......;
```

As you see all lines have the same patterns ended with semi-colons, only different vendors.
So far I tried with searching one by one, but there should a better way to achieve this:

```
preg_match("/(-webkit.*;)/", $css, $webkit);
$css = str_replace($webkit[1], '', $css);
// ... etc
```

Any hint would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE: The reason is I will use http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/, but I need a way to toggle the states for certain phase of developments, like when JS disabled.

Comment: why you want to remove it? those prefixes make sure that you get the correct result for target browser ..

Comment: there is javascript function prefixfree that I want to use, instead. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regex `/^-.*;?/m` matches every line that starts with `-`, and possible have a `;` at the end

**updated**
`/^(\s|\t)*-.*;?/m`
match anything that starts with no or more whitespace or tab, has `-` after whitespace or tab and ends with at exactly one `;`

Comment: Is there a way to also match those lines with spaces before the start "-", e.g.: "<space>-", or "<space><space>-". Thanks

Comment: updated my answer now you can check for any whitespace and tab before `-`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems I also need to add, "background-image: -" to the league ;)

Comment: `/background-image:-.*;?/m` for background-image

Answer (score 3):

Try this `(-webkit-.*?;)|(-khtml-.*?;)|(-ms-.*?;)|(-moz-.*?;)|(-o-.*?;)`

```
preg_match("/(-webkit-.*?;)|(-khtml-.*?;)|(-ms-.*?;)|(-moz-.*?;)|(-o-.*?;)/", $css, $webkit);
```